# Debug npx environment selection for nested directories?

Tags: node.js, npx

I have nested directories with different nodejs environments (`package.json` and `node_modules/`), and need to run `npx` under different environments. Something like this:

```
a/
├─ node_modules/
├─ b/
│  ├─ c/
│  │  ├─ node_modules/
│  │  ├─ package.json
├─ package.json
```

Recently, I created directory `c/`, and found that when running a command with `npx` under `c/`, it shows some warning related to `a/node_modules/`. Both environments have this command (package), to avoid confusion.

Thus, I would like to check why `npx` is unexpectedly looking at the upper levels of the directory structure.

Is there a way to output the relevant information?
For example, how do I check which (environment of) directory that `npx` is running commands in?